# Add/Remove Class Fade Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm new to development so please go easy on me :)

I've started to create a body background slider on my eCommerce platform which I hope will eventually be able to toggle through a selection of body background images (not made it that far yet).

I've managed to create a page that toggles body background images with "Previous" and "Next" buttons by removing and adding classes but the crossfading doesn't work, please see below:

https://zoeyplayground-com.zoeysite.com/lookbook

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".next").click(function() {
            jQuery("body").removeClass("bodybackground1").fadeOut('slow');
            jQuery("body").addClass("bodybackground2").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".back").click(function() {
            jQuery("body").removeClass("bodybackground2").fadeOut('slow');
            jQuery("body").addClass("bodybackground1").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="toggle" width="100%">
<img src="/media/import/back.png" class="back">
<img src="/media/import/next.png" class="next">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bodybackground1 { 
    background: url('/media/import/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.bodybackground2 {
    background: url('/media/import/background2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#toggle img {
    margin-top: 400px;
    display: inline;
}

#toggle .next {
    float: right;
}

#toggle img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Would anybody be able to please explain why the fade isn't working? Any guidance or advice is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It maybe Ideal to use z-index, then when you fade the images in and out the image behind will fade in creating that nice cross fade. But, if you spend 10 minutes online you'll find something identical to this online already built. I hope this helps.

Comment: if you inspect the css the (transition: all 0.5s;) are crossed out so add important to see if that helps -- transition: all 0.5s !important;

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @matt136: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/16962/

Comment: maverickosama92 - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. `transition: all 0.5s;` on your `.bodybackground*` classes should take care of the fade effect. There is just 1 problem, your transition property is being overwritten by this `#pix-fe` code.

```
#pix-fe {
...
transition: opacity .2s ease;
...
}
```

You should check on  it. A quick fix would be to do the following in your css:

```
#pix-fe.bodybackground1 { 
    background: url('/media/import/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#pix-fe.bodybackground2 {
    background: url('/media/import/background2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joel. This didn't actually work (maybe something to do with the platform). I did add !important to the transition though which then made it work, but it's not transitioning properly. What about the jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut(), is this necessary? Thank you.

Comment: Ah i was using Chrome inspector to test this and it worked fine. Let you know if i come up with a better fix. The jQuery fades are not necessary as you are using CSS3 transitions to run it.

Comment: @matt136 Just tried again pretty sure it should work. You can test this with Chrome inspector. Noticed you put the !important hack to make it work for now. You may want to remove it and try the following instead?

`body#pix-fe {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}`

Let me know if it works better this time.